# Vagrant vm under admin on Windows is 'poweroff' for other users

Tags: vagrant, pycharm, smb

I use Vagrant on Windows with PyCharm integration. When  I start vm as user - everything OK. But I want SMB sync and I have to run it under administrator. And if Vagrant runs under administrator others user can't see that vm runs (status poweroff). PyCharm use Vagrant as user. How to run Vagrant wint SMB on Windows and pair it with Pycharm (remote venv, Django)? Without standalone ssh connectivity (features like test server, django shell, etc. don't work).